# Beyond usual quantum mechanic description of entanglement, is there any QFT or stringy formalism/explanation of it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, quantum-entanglement

Currently entanglement is speculated to be one underlying mechanism of emergent spacetime, but what are its foundations?

Comment: Entanglement is a mathematical phenomenon similar to conditional probability, it's not a physical effect.

Comment: @David Do you have a ref for that? Entanglement might be confusing, but it is perfectly well understood in QM. You won't learn anything more about it from ST or QFT.

Comment: Have you [searched this site for related questions](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=entanglement+quantum+field+theory+is%3Aquestion)?

Comment: This is a common topic in gauge/gravity duality, e.g. see MERA, Ryu-Takayanagi. Also see "ER=EPR". i.e. don't close this question.

Comment: @MitchellPorter: Then this question should *show some research effort* and at least give one of those references, and ask a more specific question. Just saying *"Currently entanglement is speculated to be one underlying mechanism of emergent spacetime"* is very vague and doesn't tell the reader what this question actually wants to know..

Comment: @ACuriousMind I know MERA, RT and ER=EPR. My question is about the fundamental formalism of entanglement and possible ref, so I did not list references on those well-known topics.

Comment: @innisfree ref about its application was mentioned by Mitchell, but I don't have refs on what I was asking.

Comment: There are 2 different questions here. For the one of the title just browse a search on "EPR and field" . The last question has a one word answer : imagination

Comment: @DavidSun See perhaps this article and refs therein: http://www.nature.com/news/the-quantum-source-of-space-time-1.18797#/correction1. Also http://lanl.arxiv.org/pdf/1005.3035v1, which apparently started the current discussion.

Answer (score -1):

It's interesting you are asking this question.  Just few days ago an article was published in the Quanta Magazine discussing precisely this issue.  There it goes beyond what you call “the usual quantum mechanics description of entanglement”.   In the new theory, the quantum entanglement (QE) is applied not just across the space but also across the time.  By doing it and by analyzing its outcomes, scientists are hypothesizing now that the whole space-time might be originated from the QE across time and that the QE is the more fundamental structure of the universe than the space-time.

This theory corresponds well (not necessarily in QE, but in the interpretation of space-time) with the Transactional Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics as proposed by John G Cramer in 1986 and as expanded by Ruth E Kastner in 2012, in her book:  “The Transactional Interpretation of Quantum Mechanics – The Reality of Possibility”.

The recent article in Quanta Magazine is found here:
https://www.quantamagazine.org/20160119-time-entanglement/